# python time.tzname() returning "+-HH" instead of "timezone" in Ubuntu 17.04 Gnome

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am not sure this is a problem of the time.tzname attribute since this has started since I moved to Ubuntu 17.04 Gnome. But I would like to now what is the best way to handle this so that my code can keep working on other OSs versions.

Up until now, time.tzname would return something like ['BRT', 'BRTS'] which corresponds to my timezone. But now I am getting ['-03', '-02'] instead.

```
import time
time.tzname
('-03', '-02')
```

Does anyone know if I can revert it somehow to get the usual ['BRT', 'BRTS'] or this is the new standard?

Comment: Any [mcve]s in vicinity?

Comment: This is less of a problem of how to adjust my code to adapt to the new behavior than to find out why I am getting this different output from python/Ubuntu Gnome.